# How to pass message from angular template node in node red

Tags: angularjs, iot, node-red

I'm trying to pass input textbox value by clicking on button

```
<script>

var h = this.scope.myHot;
//var c = {{cold}};
var value = h;
// or overwrite value in your callback function ...
this.scope.action = function() { return value; }

</script>
<p>Hot: <input type="text" ng-model="hot" ng-value="myHot"></p>
<p>Cold: <input type="text" ng-model="cold"></p>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">
    Click me
</md-button>
```

[image: the message is always undefined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to sent the angular model values back to your node-red flow, you can use a `ui_template` node with some generic ng code like this:

```
<p>Hot: <input type="text" ng-model="myHot"></p>
<p>Cold: <input type="text" ng-model="myCold"></p>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload: {hot: myHot, cold: myCold}})">
    Send values
</md-button>
```

The returned `msg.payload` object will contains whatever values were entered into the hot and cold input fields, with this structure:

`{"hot":"123","cold":"4.5"}`

Comment: Thanks a lot SteveR , could I call another function with send() like this <md-button ng-click="send({payload: {hot: myHot, cold: myCold}}) ; dis()">

Comment: That should work, assuming the `dis()` function is in the angular scope. You can also put both the `send(...)` and `dis()` functions inside a new function and just call that on `ng-click`